# how to set php echo timer then move to another page

Tags: php

I wish after echo can wait about 2 second then move to another page ? how to do that ? using jquery ?

```
if($theme_added)
{
  echo "Theme has been successfully added.";
  window.location.href="manage_party_info.php";
}
```

Comment: umm... PHP? JavaScript? Looks like you are mixing languages here...

Comment: If you want to wait using javascript, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
header('refresh: 2; url=http://www.example.net');
```

2 = number of seconds;
url = adress

Comment: Sorry, 40 seconds too slow ;)

Comment: this is it, maybe next time:)

Comment: Are you challenging "The Sniper"? :p

Comment: why not? i'm a cheetah :D

Comment: Hmmm... Cheetahs can reach 60 miles per hour. Sniper bullets average around 500 metres per second (~1,120 miles per hour). Might need to attach some rockets to your cheetah :p

Answer (score 0):

For an instant redirect, you would do `header("Location: manage_party_info.ph");`

For a delayed one, however, you can output some JavaScript, or use a "meta refresh":

```
header("Refresh: 3; url=manage_party_info.php");
die("<p>Theme has been successfully added.</p>"
    ."<p>You will be redirected. Please <a href=\"manage_party_info.php\">click here</a> if this page appears for more than five seconds.</p>");
```

Notice how I added a manual alternative with the link. This is an essential usability thing, because some users may have disabled the Refresh header in their browser (as it can be and sometimes is used for malicious purposes). You will face this problem if you use JavaScript/jQuery too, because users can disable JS.